# how to disable a black border between my listView in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, layout

I have a listView in my android app.

There is a black border between the List items, show their bg has no such.

What property can cause that?

```
    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rtalterts_menu_listmenu"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:scrollbars="none" android:padding="0dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none">
    </ListView>
```

row xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/rtalerts_menu_row_container"
  android:padding="2dp"
  >

  <ImageView
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:id="@+id/rtalerts_menu_row_image"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:scaleType="center">
  </ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in my list adapter:

`holder.container.setBackgroundResource( R.drawable.item_selector_middle );`

Comment: 'android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your xml

```
  <ListView
        ...
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        ...
    />
```

The divider should be inserted after every entry by default.

Comment: what is the difference between `android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent` and `android:divider="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: [cacheColorHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:cacheColorHint)  is for background only.. whereas divider is for somtehing between two list items

Comment: happy that it helps u :)

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/friendlist_lv_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
 </ListView>
```

These two lines do the trick:

```
 android:divider="#00000000"
 android:dividerHeight="4dp"
```

it defines the devider to be transparent and gives it a spacing of 4px

Answer (score 0):

I think that called divider

```
listview.setDividerHeight(0);
```

and try all other other properties

Answer (score 0):

```
// set this properties to list
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:divider="@null"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set the `cacheColorHint` to black and your `ImageView` in the item doesn't fill its parent (at least due to its margin, but maybe also because its fixed width and height).

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:divider="#00000000"
    ...
/>
```